# How get dummies column which contain 2 words

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How to add dummies to pandas DataFrame whose column contains 2 words?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjnnt.png)

I try this code

```
tgl_upload = pd.get_dummies(df."Tanggal Upload")
df_baru = pd.concat([df, "Tanggal Upload"], axis=1)
```

But it says SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
    tgl_upload = pd.get_dummies(df."Tanggal Upload")
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the correct code? Thanks in advance

Comment: try: `tgl_upload = pd.get_dummies(df["Tanggal Upload"])`

Comment: It works, but how about the second line? 

Its says df_baru = pd.concat([df, ["Tanggal Upload"], axis=1)
                                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: your concat also has an error. did you mean: `df_baru = pd.concat([df, tgl_upload], axis=1)`

Comment: It workss. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome!